# How to add new command in moderncv template?

Tags: moderncv

I want to add new `moderncv` command to act like address command exactly, I mean in format and positioning except that I will called this time `\address2` here is a quick demonstration of what I want, here is the original commands

```
\firstname{ }
\familyname{ }
\address{ }{ }    
\mobile{ }                    
\email{ }
```

what I want is something like this

```
\firstname{ }
\familyname{ }
\address{ }{ }
\address2{ }{ }    
\mobile{ }                    
\email{ }
```

and this will give final result like the original one but `\address2` after original address, How can I do such thing?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) style that you're using: `casual` (default), `classic`, `oldstyle` or `banking`. For the default `casual`, you can add the following to your document preamble (*after* `\moderncvstyle{casual}`, if you're using it):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[2]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \flushfooter}}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \addressfont\color{color2}%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@familyname}\\
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \flushfooter}}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother
```

The above just redefines the footer for both the CV and the letter part of the document. This will allow you two use

```
\firstname{ }
\familyname{ }
\address{ }{ }
\addresstwo{ }{ }    
\mobile{ }                    
\email{ }
```

Note that numbers are not allowed for control sequences, hence `\addresstwo` instead of `\address2`. Taking the base example from `moderncv` ([`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex)) and inserting the above code yields:

[image]

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2012 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[2]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \flushfooter}}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \addressfont\color{color2}%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@familyname}\\
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \flushfooter}}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother

% moderncv themes
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}    % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                             % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                         % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}        % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title (optional)}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\addresstwo{more streets}{more city}          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                        % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}            % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                  % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted
\quote{Some quote (optional)}                 % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                     % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}            % change the symbol for lists

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% for BibTeX numerical labels
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                         % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

---

Here are the required changes to the `classic` style to incorporate a second address for both the CV and letter head (this should be added to the document preamble *after* a call to `\moderncvstyle{classic}`):

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[2]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscitytwo}}% if \addresstreettwo is defined, \addresscitytwo will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional picture box
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@familyname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscitytwo}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \hbox{\today}\\[2em]% US informal style: "April 6, 2006"; UK formal style: "05/04/2006"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Werner, Such a very elegant solution. Sadly, with the changes to ModernCV, it doesn't quite work correctly any more. Is it possible to have you update these solutions, or at least the one for {casual}? I tried doing it myself by adding in the correct "addresscountrytwo" commands, but it seems the changes to the .sty file were to great for me to overcome. I'm also interested in adding in a \mobilephonetwo, but hopefully the update will allow me to do that on my own. Thank you for any help you can provide.