# How to add a second e-mail address with moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` to write my CV. I'm using the `classic` style and I want to add a second e-mail address. It doesn't work if I simply do that:

```
\mail{email1}

\mail{email2}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is very similar to [How to add new command in `moderncv` template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58586/5764)

Comment: Do you need each email to have its own logo?

Comment: yes, that would be better if each e-mail had a logo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need to do is to define a newcommand (say, `\emailtwo`), completely analogous to `\email` as defined in `moderncv.cls` and then to modify appropriately the `\makecvtitle` command (as implemented in `moderncvclassic.sty`) to conditionally include the information for this new field:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\emailtwo}[1]{\def\@emailtwo{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscitytwo}}% if \addresstreettwo is defined, \addresscitytwo will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@emailtwo}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@emailtwo}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional picture box
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@familyname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscitytwo}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \hbox{\today}\\[2em]% US informal style: "April 6, 2006"; UK formal style: "05/04/2006"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email{firstemail@gmail.com}
\emailtwo{secondemail@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting document:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

A much simpler way, which also includes the email symbol is:

```
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{email@email.com}}
```

so:

```
\email{emailOne@email.com}
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{emailTwo@email.com}}
```

Comment: This will add the second email at the end of all the information. Two emails will get separated if `\homepage` has value.

Answer (score 4):

Another, a bit simpler, option would be to write for example:

```
\mobile{phone1 \\ phone2  \\}
```

Or

```
\address{address1 \\ address2 \\}
```

You only get one logo, hence it might not be exactly what you are looking for, but it turned out to be the preferred option for me.

Comment: it does not work with the `\email{}` field

Answer (score 4):

An easier (and cleaner than redefining the whole `\maketitle` macro) solution:

```
\renewcommand{\emaillink}[1]{#1} % prevent a non-sensical mailto link
\email{EMAIL1\makenewline\emailsymbol{}EMAIL2}
```

If you still want clickable emails, you can use `\href{mailto:EMAIL}{EMAIL}`.

Answer (score 1):

As result of merging [p4bl0's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339992/225691) and [Jens Laursen's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163969/225691) answers, I wrote the following code.

```latex
\let\myemaillink\emaillink
\let\myemailsymbol\emailsymbol
\renewcommand{\emaillink}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\emailsymbol}{}
\email{
  \myemailsymbol \myemaillink{parsa.mohammadian@sharif.edu}
  or
  \myemailsymbol \myemaillink{parsa2820@gmail.com}
}
```

This fixes [Jens Laursen's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163969/225691) answer problem mentioned by [Tirtha R](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/175027/tirtha-r) in comments.

[image]